# how to filter a query based on 2 fields

Tags: sql, select

I have a table:

```
user_qualifications:
  id
  user_id
  type
  title
  description
```

I need to get all the fields based on 2 filters... like work experience and education. These will be types. Do I need to make 2 queries? I need to display all his work experience and all his education, it could be multiple rowsets foreach type.

Comment: Can you give some example data from `user_qualifactions` and the example output you want?

Comment: Even for homework this is a bit too simple question.

Comment: @SzilardBarany - Except that this ***appears*** to be an EAV table, and does not have the fields "work_exp" and "education" that are referenced in AvidProgrammer's answer.  And anyone that thinks it is `trivial` to write these queries against EAV has long since forgotten what it's like the first time you have to deal with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
select id, user_id, type, title, description
from   user_qualifications
where  Work_exp = 2 and education="MS"
```

Comment: and when i do not have ms and only work exp then it will break

Comment: And the two fields you use in your where clause simply don't exist in the OP's schema.

Answer (score 0):

Without an answer to my question in comments I can only make an educated guess as to what you really need.

I think you want something like...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  user_qualifications
WHERE
  type IN ('work experience', 'education')
```

Answer (score 0):

The post by AvidProgrammer should not include the Double quotes instead use the single quotes otherwise you will get a compile error

```
SELECT id, user_id, type, title, description
FROM user_qualifications
WHERE experience = 2 and education = 'BSC'
```